# R zoo package 2.13.2 64-bit windows 7 error message

Tags: r

I recently "upgraded" R from 2.11 to 2.13.2 (huge mistake, wish I'd never done it (if it ain't broken...)) and am having trouble getting some packages to work.  Below is what happens when I try to use and then reinstall the `zoo` package.  For the record, I'm using Windows 7 with 64-bit R-2.13.2.  Any suggestions?

```
> ## univariate plotting
> x <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)
Error: could not find function "zoo"
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/2.13/zoo_1.7-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1387309 bytes (1.3 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 1.3 Mb

package 'zoo' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded packages are in
        C:\Users\backupSam\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpitXEFu\downloaded_packages
> local({pkg <- select.list(sort(.packages(all.available = TRUE)),graphics=TRUE)
+ if(nchar(pkg)) library(pkg, character.only=TRUE)})
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'zoo'
```

EDIT:

```
> install.packages("zoo") 
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/backupSam/Documents/R/win-library/2.13’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/2.13/zoo_1.7-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1387309 bytes (1.3 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 1.3 Mb

package 'zoo' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded packages are in
        C:\Users\backupSam\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpitXEFu\downloaded_packages
> require(zoo)
Loading required package: zoo
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
> library(zoo)
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package/namespace load failed for 'zoo'
```

Comment: Works for me on 32 bit Vista R 2.13.2 .  Are you able to get any packages to install at all?  What about if you try it from a different mirror?  What happens if you try R 2.14.0?

Comment: What happens if you just type: require(zoo) ?

Comment: I'm running same OS/R versions that you are and no trouble.  have you tried install.packages("zoo") and then library(zoo)?

Comment: No way I'm changing versions again, 11 -> 13 has been a nightmare.

Comment: See above edit for what I've tried to do. Also tried downloading from another mirror with same results.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that your upgrade was a nightmare.  I've upgraded every release since I started working with R-2.10.1 and always found the upgrade process quite benign.  Anyway, I'm using the same OS and version as you and also have no problems.  So, I can offer you my sympathy but sadly no new advice.  Good luck.

Comment: Same OS/R version here, and no problems. Also tried R 2.14.0, no problems either. Ah, and my change from 2.13.2 to 2.14 was effortless, maybe that's worth a try (start with a clean library to prevent errors)?

Comment: About trying R 2.14.0 its really no big deal. Just download, run installer (typically just press Enter repeatedly) and its installed.  You can have many versions of R installed at the same time. I probably have half a dozen.  You can use RSetReg.exe to change  current version or `Rversions.bat` in http://batchfiles.googlecode.com which will list all versions you have if run without args or it will switch to the version listed in arg1 if given.  To switch versions, use it from an Administrator console (e.g. el.js cmd /k Rversions.bat R-2.13.2 where el.js is also from the batchfiles site.)

Comment: Ended up going w/ 2.14; was painless.  Thanks for the advice.  If you throw it in an answer I'll give you credit.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, am moving comment to an answer.

Try repeating the process with R 2.14.0 (download it, run the installer and likely you will just have to press Enter repeatedly until its installed).

One can have multiple versions of R installed at the same time so there is no worry about losing the old one.   Use `RSetReg.exe` (found in a subfolder of the bin folder in each R distribution) to make that version of R the current one.  Alternately use `Rversions.bat` in [the batchfiles googlecode project](http://batchfiles.googlecode.com) to do it.  Without args `Rversions.bat` lists the available versions and with a single arg it makes that one the version current.  (Note that switching versions requires that you run the relevant command in elevated mode, e.g. `el.js cmd /k Rversions.bat R-2.14.0` where `el.js` is also found in the batchfiles project.)

EDIT:

Added info on `el.js` .